# The boundary of a convex set is represented by a strictly convex function?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

I an intricate with something.

Let $S$ be a $C^2$-hypersurface that is the boundary of a convex and compact set $C$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n >1$. Let $0 \in int(C)$ and define a function $F: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ that is $\alpha$-homogeneous, with $\alpha >1$ and $F(x) = 1$ if, and only if, $x \in S$.

My questions: $F$ is strictly convex?

And can I say That, $F$ is twice differentiable at $\mathbb{R}^n-\{0\}$? And $F''(x) \geq 0$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^n-\{0\}$? Where $''$ indicates derivative in $x$.

I searched on the internet and some literature a little and could not find anything that indicates that this is true.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: There is no need for $F$ to be differentiable. Take $F(x)=x^{\alpha}$ for $x\geq 0$ and $F(x)=2|x|^{\alpha}$ for $x<0$. However, this example is strictly convex still (assuming $\alpha>1$). Of course this depends on your definition of “homogeneous function” (even Wikipedia gives two non-equivalent definitions, one for scaling by a real number, another for scaling by a nonnegative real number).

Comment: Hi @Michael. I am using the following definition: F is $\alpha$-homogeneous if $F(\lambda x) = \lambda^{\alpha}F(x)$, $\forall \lambda >0$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: (My above comment should have said *twice* differentiable.) So for example $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by $$F(x)  =\left\{\begin{array}{cc} x^2 & \mbox{ if $x\geq 0$} \\ 2x^2 & \mbox{ if $x<0$} \end{array}\right.$$ is $2$-homogeneous, satisfies $F(1)=F(-((1/2)^{1/2}))=1$, but is not twice differentiable.

Comment: Hi @Michael. I will change the hypothesis. But I want $0$ in the interior of my convex set. So If you take $[-1,1]$ the convex set, you have $S=\{-1,1\}$ and $F(-1) = 2 \neq 1$. Am I right? I think that $F$ will assume the regularity of $S$, but I do not know for sure.

Comment: The function $F$ in Michael's comment is what we get if we want $F$ to be $2$-homogeneous and the convex set is $[-\frac1{\sqrt2}, 1]$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Right! Thank you! I corrected the question about the strictly convex and the differential. Maybe in dimension $1$ it is not true. But in higher dimensions, I think it can be true that $F$ will assume the regularity of the boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that the convex set $\text{conv}(S)$ you start with is bounded and contains $0$, because otherwise the definition of $F$ is a bit funky. But under these assumptions, for every $\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^n - \{0\}$, there is a unique $\mathbf s \in S$ such that $\mathbf x = \lambda \mathbf s$, where $\lambda > 0$.

Asking for your function $F$ to be $\alpha$-homogeneous means defining $F(\mathbf x) = \lambda^\alpha$, where $\lambda$ is the value found above. I'm going to show that more is true: if $h$ is any increasing convex function on the positive reals, then defining $F(\mathbf x) = h(\lambda)$ will make $F$ convex.

We'll need the following lemma from affine geometry: in the diagram below, $$\frac{OB'}{OB} =  \frac{B'C'}{A'C'}\cdot \frac{OA'}{OA} +  \frac{A'B'}{A'C'}\cdot \frac{OC'}{OC}.$$

[image]

I'm not going to prove the lemma, but it's not hard to do with standard geometry tools (or with coordinates).

Let $\mathbf x, \mathbf y \in \mathbb R^n$ be two points, and let $0 < t < 1$. We want to show that $$F(t \mathbf x + (1-t)\mathbf y) \le t F(\mathbf x) + (1-t) F(\mathbf y).$$

To this end, pick $A', B', C'$ in the diagram above to be $\mathbf x$, $t \mathbf x + (1-t)\mathbf y$, and $\mathbf y$; let $O$ be the origin. Let $A$ and $B$ be the points of $S$ on lines $OA', OC'$. By the convexity of $\text{conv}(S)$, $B \in \text{conv}(S)$.

By convexity of $h$ and the lemma, $$h(\frac{OB'}{OB}) \le  \frac{B'C'}{A'C'}h(\frac{OA'}{OA}) + \frac{A'B'}{A'C'} h(\frac{OC'}{OC}).$$ Here, $\frac{B'C'}{A'C'} = t$, $h(\frac{OA'}{OA}) = F(\mathbf x)$, $\frac{A'B'}{A'C'} = 1-t$, and $h(\frac{OC'}{OC})$, so the RHS of this is $t F(\mathbf x) + (1-t) F(\mathbf y)$.

On the other hand, by convexity of the set $\text{conv}(S)$, $OB$ intersects $S$ somewhere at a point $B^*$ with $OB^* > OB$. Therefore $F(t \mathbf x + (1-t)\mathbf y) = h(\frac{OB'}{OB^*}) \le h(\frac{OB'}{OB})$, where we use the fact that $h$ is increasing. This shows that $F$ is convex.

---

In your question, you ask for strict convexity, but the condition you mean by that is doubly unclear. First of all, $F''(\mathbf x)$ is a weird thing to write. Do you mean the Hessian matrix of $F$? Are you asking for this to be positive semidefinite? Second, this second derivative check only corresponds to convexity, not strict convexity.

In fact, if $S$ contains line segments, it's easy to see that by the usual definition of strict convexity, $F$ will not be strictly convex (because $F$ will be $1$ along line segments in $S$). But if $S$ does not contain line segments, and if $h$ is either strictly convex or strictly increasing, we do get strict convexity.

Comment: Hi @MishaLavrov. You are right, $0$ is in the interior of my convex set, that you named $conv(S)$ and it is bounded. I know that $F''(x)$ is weird, but I am already used to it. I read some papers with these notations.  I mean the Hessian matrix of $F$ and I am asking to be positive semidefinite.  Thank you very much for your answer. It was very helpful. In fact, the way you proved, do you think we could extend this to starshaped domains?

Comment: You mean if we start with a set that is star convex instead of convex? I don't think so; we are really using the fact that if we take two points in $S$ (on the boundary of the set), such as the points $A$ and $C$ above, then any point $B$ on the line segment between them will be contained in the set.

Comment: I was redoing the calculations you propose and I think $\frac{A'B'}{A'C'} = (1-t)$ because $\frac{tx + (1-t)y - x}{y-x} = \frac{-(1-t)x + (1-t)y}{y-x} = (1-t)$.

Comment: You're right; but I think that's because the lemma was also backwards and we can just switch everything around to fix it.

Comment: You are saying to switch $\frac{OA'}{OA}$ with $\frac{OC'}{OC}$ in the lemma?

Comment: Yes, I think I've made all the corrections in my answer now.